# type mismatch; found : newValue.type (with underlying type S) required: T

Tags: scala

What I want to do is :

```
class ListField[+T] extends Field[MutableList[T]] {

  value = Some(new MutableList[T]())

  def +=[S >: T](newValue: S): Unit = add(newValue)

  def add[S >: T](newValue: S): Unit = value.map(l => {

    if (writable_? || !initialized_?) {
```

On the following line I get:

> type mismatch; found : newValue.type (with underlying type S)
>   required: T

```
      l += newValue
      validate
      makeDirty
      change0.fire(l)
  }
})

def length: Int = list.length
//etc
```

How do I do this?  Is it possible?  If I don't make T co-variant everything works as is.

Field is:

```
class Field[T] extends Signal[T] with ChangeStateTracking {

  private[this] var data: Option[T] = None

  private var writable = true

  def writable_? = writable

  override def now = data.get

  def value: Option[T] = data

  def validate: ValidationNel[FieldError, Option[T]] = value.successNel[FieldError]
//etc
```

NOTE: The code actually works & compiles if I don't want T to b covariant (ie T instead of +T).  It's only when I try and make T covariant that I get the error.

I want an optional list of +T, that can change.

Comment: You try to add l and newValue which are of different types (even though S is a subtype of T) and I guess you have to define this operation explicitly.

Comment: Isn't MutableList invariant?

Comment: YES.  I didn't bother to check the signature of mutable list.  It is indeed T while List is +T.  I'll have to try it with list and see.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the type of `l` is `MutableList[T]`, so you obviously cannot call `+=` with some other type.

I suspect you assumed `l` would be of type `ListField` for some reason, in which case the `+=` called would not be `MutableList`'s, but `ListField`'s.

Comment: No, not at all, I expect 'l' to be T or a descendant of T.

Comment: @JimBarrows `value`is `Option[MutableList[T]]`. You need to map twice to get `T`.

Comment: If I was replacing the list, correct.  However I'm adding to the list, so I only have to map the option.